# How to describe this object's shape in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript1.8

The object looks like a mixture of dictionary and regular JavaScript object:

```
var obj = {
  'dynamic prop1': { },
  'dynamic prop2': function () { },
  'dynamic prop3': function () { },
  'dynamic prop4': function () { },

  func: function() {},
  prop: null
};
```

The majority of the properties assigned to object will be represented by string-based ('dynamic prop') properties and will contain either object or function.

Additionally it will contain two additional properties: prop and func.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some text so it's not a code-only answer.

```
interface MyObjType {
  [key: string]: (() => void) | { maybeYouHaveSomePropertiesToDeclare?: string };
  func(): void;
  prop: any;
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with mixing string indexers and real properties. Compiler says that func is not assignable to string indexer.

Comment: The string index type has to be assignable from the type of all properties (hence the first part of the union type shown in the example).

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!